# Selenium webdriver does not quit chrome driver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using `Selenium webdriver` but it don't quit `chrome` and `chrome` driver properly . Some of processes staid runner.

code for quitting chrome :

```
 driver.quit();
```

code for starting chrome :

```
 System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/<path to chrome driver>/chromedriver");
 ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
 options.setBinary(new File("/<path to chrome >/google-chrome"));
 driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

> Chrome driver version :2.9.248304
>   Chromium version :40.0.2214.115
>   Selenium version :2.32
>   OS: Linux 
>   java.version: 1.7.0_71

Thanks in advance ,
Naira

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Why are you using selenium `2.32`? - it is very very old, upgrade to the latest (`2.45`).

Comment: How did you **guarantee** that your `driver.quit()` actually got executed?

Comment: if it didn't quit chrome then its sure it didn't encountered driver.quit or u might have lost reference to the chrome window.

Comment: There is no errors just chrome processes stays .  I will try to change selenium version . As I understand driver.quit kill chrome processes , but it didn't kill properly or may be there is problem wit selenium version ?

Answer (score -11, accepted):

The problem was with driver.quit() method only for Chrome. The driver quit didnt work properly it didnt kill all processes of chrome (including child processes). What I did. I changed Selenium jar codes to fix this for my project , unfortunatly I cant share my code caus of project rules which dont allow to share any type of code .

Comment: You're bound by IP agreements, sure. But, there is nothing wrong in explaining the logic, if you have one. That's not IP.

Answer (score 5):

Are you executing your driver.quit() within a finally block?

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/<path to chrome driver>/chromedriver");
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setBinary(new File("/<path to chrome >/google-chrome"));
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
try
{
    //automated steps
}
finally
{
    driver.quit();
}
```

Comment: Driver quit work . I see it by logs and when i run local to .
But processes collected again and again

Comment: Yes . Also I use selenium 2.45 now. But processes still collect . What can I do ?

Comment: You should also put the driver.quit() into a second try {} catch {} block! It may throw.

Answer (score 3):

I solved them this way:

```
import os

os.system('killall chrome')
```

It is useful if you don't use Google Chrome for something else.

Answer (score 3):

It works fine for me if I use

```
driver.close();
driver.quit();
```

Answer (score 3):

So, nothing worked for me. What I ended up doing was setting a unique ID on my addArguments to launch chromedriver, then when I want to quit I do something like this:

```
opts.addArguments(...args, 'custom-pid-' + randomId());
```

Then to make sure it quits:

```
await this.driver.close()
await this.driver.quit()

spawn(`kill $(ps aux | grep ${RANDOM_PID_HERE} | grep -v "grep" | awk '{print $2}')`)
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Get the driver as singleton

```
@Singleton
class BrowserInstance {

ChromeDriver getDriver(){
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions()
    options.addArguments("--headless --disable-gpu")
    return new ChromeDriver(options)
   }
}
```

2) Use Close and quit in finally block

```
 finally {
        chromeDriver.close()
        chromeDriver.quit()
    }
```

Result: you will be using only one instance at time and if you see task manager you will not find chromedriver and chrome process hanging.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Object Pool pattern for Web drivers in this scenario as below:
*
* This class creates the pool of WebDriver instances as defined in the Main.java class by final variable "DRIVER_INSTANCES" and from that Main class we instantiate this pool

```
public class WebDriverPool {
    public static Vector<WebDriver> driverPools = new Vector<WebDriver>();
    
    public static void initializeWebDriverPool() {
        for(int i=0; i<Main.DRIVER_INSTANCES; i++) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");

            // Add options to Google Chrome. The window-size is important for responsive sites
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            //options.addArguments("headless");
            options.addArguments("window-size=1200x600");
            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
            driverPools.add(driver);
        }
        System.out.println("Driver pool initialized");
    }
    
    public static WebDriver getAndRemove() {
        WebDriver driver = driverPools.get(0);
        driverPools.remove(0);
        return driver;
    }
    
    /*
     * When our all the task are finished then this method is called from the Main.java class to close the running chrome instances
     */
    public static void quitAllDrivers() {
        for(WebDriver driver: driverPools) {
            driver.quit();
        }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, driver.quit() is working and killing all the process, no problem with that. But each time I use driver.close(), process remains. If I use it 10 times, 10 process stays on background process until I killed them programmatically or manually. Also driver.close() is giving some warnings at the end of running program most of the time like after closing browser

[WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, retrying...