# How to close and reopen browser instance again in a loop?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

My goal was to scrape data from a website but after a long run (about 3-4 hours), the browsing speed decreased significantly. So after a specific time of loop, I want to close the browser and open it again to clear the memory. Here's my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options = Options()
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\Name\\Desktop\\ProjectProfile\\1") #Path to your chrome profile
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
options.set_capability("pageLoadStrategy", "eager")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.maximize_window()
x = 0
while x <= 10:
    driver.get("https://example.com")
    My_code()
    if x == 5:
        driver.quit() #this would get me No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it error
        driver.close() #this would get me Invalid session id error
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

I encountered 2 errors when using `driver.close()` and `driver.quit()` and when it opened a new browser instance, the cookies from the Chrome profile didn't exist (the account doesn't log in).

I have searched to find the solution on Google but nothing helped.

Comment: any session values stored/created (cookies/local storage/etc...) during that first Selenium session will be gone.  These are stored in a temp file.  You can't use them anyway because when you re-launch the driver/browser, you will have a new session.  Just re-login to the site in the new session.  You should also use a bit of sleep between quitting one driver and beginning a new one.  (This gives the browser time to cleanup...)

Comment: Yeah, I can handle with the cookies isn't being save just fine, just log in again. But the problem still insist. When the browser relaunch, I get the error ```No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it``` How can I resolve this ?

Comment: Make sure to use a long enough sleep between quitting one driver and creating a new one.  And don't use detach flag.

Comment: I just figured it out myself by construct the code again line by line and run it. And the code above isn't the problem. The problem is it get conflict with the ```wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "xxx")))``` line. I cant use it when the browser reopen. Dont know why, I am so confused. Had to use implicit wait after this

Answer (score 0):

For the error during closing and quitting, it on various stackoverflow answer ([there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44016118) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62631732)) you need to `close` first and after `quit`.

For the cookie matter, it's because you don't use option again. With the following code it should be better:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

def get_driver()
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\Name\\Desktop\\ProjectProfile\\1") #Path to your chrome profile
    options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
    options.set_capability("pageLoadStrategy", "eager")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    driver.maximize_window()
    return driver

driver = get_driver()

x = 0
while x <= 10:
    driver.get("https://example.com")
    My_code()
    if x == 5:
        driver.close()
        driver.quit()
        driver = get_driver()
```

Comment: I have tried your code, I still get the same error when the browser reopen
```urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=54444): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/6587387389be3d985c427378f610cca4/element (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000002B44B247D50>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))```

Comment: It still navigate to the website but without the cookies so the account doesnt log in and get the above error